# Function float argument takes 0 value inside the function when I call func Task.Run

Tags: c#, .net, function, windows-runtime, task

```
private float _PhAvg;
```

**_pHAVg assign**

```
_PhAvg = DatabaseReader._Parameters
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.SpecificReg == RegCodes.phScode)
    ?.CurrentValue?.Average() ?? -9999;
```

**check _pHAvg**

`Console.WriteLine("pH :" + _pHAVg);`   **Output** `pH:6,77`

**Call method**

```
Task.Run(() => _SampleCheck.SampleLimitCheck(_PhAvg, _AkmAvg, _CodAvg));
```

**And that is `SampleLimitCheck` method**

```
public void SampleLimitCheck(float PhAverage, float AkmAverage, float CodAverage)
{
    Console.WriteLine("pH :" + PhAverage);
}
```

**Check PhAverage**

`Console.WriteLine("pH :" + PhAverage);`   **Output** `pH:0`

I give float values to the function sometimes correct but some times  appear as 0 in the function.

When I call `Task.Run(() => _SampleCheck.SampleLimitCheck(_PhAvg, _AkmAvg, _CodAvg));` I see values are 0 in function. Not all the times. Sometimes 0 sometimes I get the correct values.

But when I call `_SampleCheck.SampleLimitCheck(_PhAvg, _AkmAvg, _CodAvg)` I always catch the correct value.

What is wrong with `Task.Run()`?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how the code proceeds is a little difficult to know what it might be.

But since it's a Task, I can guess why you're reading the result before it's ready.

Task.Run(() => _SampleCheck.SampleLimitCheck(_PhAvg, _AkmAvg, _CodAvg));
Debug.WriteLine("-----");

In this example even before _SampleCheck.SampleLimitCheck finishes the Debug will be run.

If you need the result you must make sure the task is finished first.

Comment: Im not reading the result. I see all values are 0 in func.. as follow 

`
public void SampleLimitCheck(float PhAverage, float AkmAverage, float CodAverage)
{
      Console.WriteLine("Ph : "+PhAvarage)
}
`
`output Ph : 0`

Answer (score 0):

As it's currently written, it's hard to know exactly what you're question.

I guess

- `_PhAvg` is member field.
- `Run.Task` is executed before the correct value is obtained in the asynchronous thread, so `_PhAvg` is member default value.

Wrong code

```cs
Task.Run(() => _PhAvg = 10);
Task.Run(() => _SampleCheck.SampleLimitCheck(_PhAvg, _AkmAvg, _CodAvg));
```

Right code

```cs
await Task.Run(() => _PhAvg = 10);
await Task.Run(() => _SampleCheck.SampleLimitCheck(_PhAvg, _AkmAvg, _CodAvg));
```

The principle is to ensure that the `_PhAvg` assignment must precede the `Task.Run`.

Comment: The code should be continuous and can be run after a little modification